Can we use fisher scoring on a restricted likelihood function?
I have a question on how to optimize the RMLE in mixed effects regression models.
Starting with a mixed effects model:
$$y = X\beta + Zu + e$$
$$u \sim N(0, G), \quad e \sim N(0, R)$$
Where:

$y$ is the $n \times 1$ vector of observations
$X$ is the $n \times p$ design matrix for fixed effects
$\beta$ is the $p \times 1$ vector of fixed effects
$Z$ is the $n \times q$ design matrix for random effects
$u$ is the $q \times 1$ vector of random effects
$e$ is the $n \times 1$ vector of residuals

The marginal distribution of $y$ is (Where $V = ZGZ^T + R$):
$$y \sim N(X\beta, V)$$
If we define $K = I - X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$ and  $y^* = Ky$. The distribution of $y^*$ is:
$$y^* \sim N(0, KVK^T)$$
The log-likelihood of $y^*$ is (note: there are no fixed effect terms in the RMLE, only mixed effect terms, i.e. variances):
$$\begin{align*}
L(\theta) &= -\frac{1}{2}\log|KVK^T| - \frac{1}{2}y^{*T}(KVK^T)^{-1}y^* \\
&= -\frac{1}{2}\log|KVK^T| - \frac{1}{2}y^TK^T(KVK^T)^{-1}Ky
\end{align*}$$
Doing some more algebra, we get the final form of the RMLE log-likelihood:
$$L(\theta) = -\frac{1}{2}\log|V| - \frac{1}{2}\log|X^TV^{-1}X| - \frac{1}{2}y^TPy + \text{constant}$$
How do we typically optimize the above RMLE? I suppose some quasi-newton techniques can be used (e.g. BFGS), but I was wondering is it still possible to calculate the expected Fisher Information of the RMLE and use Fisher Scoring here, or is just do something like Iterative Reweighted Least Squares using the actual hessian??

I don't know too much about the theory, but the documentation of SAS PROC MIXED contains quite a bit of details & references on (some of) the ways these models can be fit. It is definitely possible to use Fisher scoring because that procedure contains an option for it.

thanks ... I will check it out

I don't know about "typically", but lme4 in R defaults to Powell's BOBYQA as wrapped in the nloptr package, which requires smoothness but does not use derivatives.
